# Only using grid Tkinter but still getting TclError

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry, label

So I just started using Google Colab and I keep getting this error:

```
TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

I'm trying to make a GUI window that takes in the information from the user and saves it.

Everything I've read online says that the issue is that I'm using `pack()` and `grid()`, but I'm only using `grid()`. The error starts when I first try to place my labels (`sourceLabel`).

I'm so confused, any help would be great.

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    from Tkinter import *

#creates window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("File Information")

window.rowconfigure([0,1], minsize=30)
window.columnconfigure([0, 1, 2, 3], minsize=30)


#this program opens the file with information and adds the new information to it
def saveInfo():
    value = path.get()
    loc = source.get()
    recode = recoding.get()
    #change name of file and will this make them see everything
    #f = open("./info.txt", "a+")
    #f.write("Source Data File Location: " + loc + ", Complete File Path: " + value + ", Is recoding of column names and/or values desired?: " + recode)
    #f.flush() 
    #f.seek(0)
    #content = f.read()
    #print (content)
    finalList = [value,loc,recode]
    #f.close()
    window.withdraw()
    print (finalList)
    return finalList



#creates a text label, fg=foreground and bg=background, theyre the locations of colors, width and height are measured by text units which are separate horizonatal and vertical
sourceLabel = tk.Label(
  text="Source Data File Location:",
  width = 21,
  height=2)
#adds text to window
sourceLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)

#creates second label
pathLabel = tk.Label(
  text="Complete File Path:",
  width = 20,
  height=2)
#adds text to window
pathLabel.grid(row=1,column=0)

#creates third label
sourceLabel = tk.Label(
  text="Is recoding of column \n names and/or values \n desired:",
  width = 20,
  height=4)
#adds text to window
sourceLabel.grid(row=2,column=0)

#create dropdown for sources
source = StringVar(window)
source.set("Local") # default value
sourceOption = OptionMenu(window, source, "Local", "Google Drive", "One Drive")
sourceOption.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ew")

#adds path entry
path = tk.Entry(fg="black", bg="white", width=35)
#adds path to window
path.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="ew")

#create dropdown for recoding
recoding = StringVar(window)
recoding.set("Yes") # default value
recodingOption = OptionMenu(window, recoding, "Yes", "No")
recodingOption.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="new")
      
#creates the click to save button
button = tk.Button(
    text="Click to Save",
    width=10,
    height=1,
    bg="white",
    fg="black", command=saveInfo
)

#adds Button to window 
button.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky="w")


#runs window
window.mainloop()
window.destroy()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the geometry manager problem with the code in your question. I get a different error when closing the application window on the `window.destroy()` call on the last line (because the application windows has already be detroyed at that point.

Comment: What did you do for the error to appear? Also you don't need the `window.destroy()` at the end.

Comment: The code you posted cannot give the error you say it does. Please copy and paste this code into a new file, run it, and then show us the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Are those widgets to be created in a window other than the root window?

Comment: Try specify the parent (`window`) when creating the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weird error you had here, I just re-wrote your code using the canvas and pack method, instead of a grid, rows, and columns. Just make sure you are using Python3x Just so none of these weird bugs resurface, hope this helps, you can play around with the x and y values at the bottom, and you can mess with the height and width values at the top when we set the canvas. Happy coding!

```
from tkinter import *

global path, source, recoding  # Global Values so that save_info can get the values
# Creates window
root = Tk()
root.title("File Information")

# Canvas Creates the base layer for the window, so instead of l = Label(text="Test").grid(row=2, column=3)
# We would now do l = Label(text="Test") 
# canvas.create_window(20, 30, anchor="nw", window=l)
canvas = Canvas(width=400, height=300)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
# Canvas.pack() just finishes creating the canvas.

# This program opens the file with information and adds the new information to it.
def save_info():
    global path, source, recoding
    value = path.get()
    loc = source.get()
    recode = recoding.get()
    # change name of file and will this make them see everything
    # f = open("./info.txt", "a+")
    # f.write("Source Data File Location: " + loc + ", Complete File Path: " + value + ", Is recoding of column names and/or values desired?: " + recode)
    # f.flush()
    # f.seek(0)
    # content = f.read()
    # print (content)
    finalList = [value, loc, recode]
    # f.close()
    root.withdraw()
    print(finalList)
    return finalList


sourceLabel = Label(
    text="Source Data File Location:",
    width=21,
    height=2)

pathLabel = Label(
    text="Complete File Path:",
    width=20,
    height=2)

recoding_label = Label(
    text="Is recoding of column \n names and/or values \n desired:",
    width=20,
    height=4)

source = StringVar(root)
source.set("Local")  # default value
sourceOption = OptionMenu(root, source, "Local", "Google Drive", "One Drive")

path = Entry(fg="black", bg="white", width=35)

recoding = StringVar(root)
recoding.set("Yes")  # default value
recodingOption = OptionMenu(root, recoding, "Yes", "No")

button = Button(
    text="Click to Save",
    width=10,
    height=1,
    bg="white",
    fg="black", command=save_info
)

# Since we are now using canvas, we must add all the elements using canvas.create_window, the first int is the x value, 2nd is the y
# Just leave anchor always as nw, and windows need to equal the variable of the widget they need to add
canvas.create_window(0, 50, anchor="nw", window=sourceLabel)
canvas.create_window(0, 90, anchor="nw", window=pathLabel)
canvas.create_window(0, 140, anchor="nw", window=recoding_label)

canvas.create_window(150, 50, anchor="nw", window=sourceOption)
canvas.create_window(150, 90, anchor="nw", window=path)
canvas.create_window(150, 140, anchor="nw", window=recodingOption)
canvas.create_window(150, 225, anchor="nw", window=button)
root.mainloop()

# I refactored some of the variables so they would be unique
```